# Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu Server 12.04 Not Working

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, virtualhost

I know this has been asked a thousand times, and I have went through just about every solution, and I still can not get this to work. I'm trying to be able to get to example.com both internally and externally. I am fairly new to servers, so I don't really know what I doing wrong, or not doing.

As per everyone's instructions I setup the site at: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com` and this is what's in the file:

```
<VirtalHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/httpdocs
    <Director />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/example/httpdocs>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow, deny
        allow form all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/example/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/www/example/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is what I have in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
12.345.67.89 example.com
```

I then did a `sudo a2ensite example.com`, then a `sudo service apache2 reload` as it told me. Now, I did a port forwarding on my internal IP (192.168.1.100) to the external IP (12.345.67.89) with port 80, and if I was to go into the browser and type 12.345.67.89/example/httpdocs, I can see my page. But, if I was to type example.com or www.example.com I get the DNS search page. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there something I'm missing? Thank you in advanced...

Answer (score 0):

I assume, your example.com vhost-file is named with starting letter a,b,c or d. So it is alphabetically before the default vhost conf-file.

If that's the case, you can rename the default conf-file (for example) to 000-default

Also make shure, your default conf-file hasn't the same ServerName in it.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply, and second, I apologize for the delay in my response. I was out of town during the Thanksgiving weekend, and didn't have much of an internet connection. I still can't get it to work. It seems that it's only reading off the default site. I even tried to disable the default and just have my example.com site enabled, but it wouldn't read any of the directories I listed. New to this, so I apologize in advance.

Comment: Please try to change your /etc/hosts file to: 127.0.0.1 example.com

Comment: I have a domain registered. Do still put the localhost IP for it?

Comment: If the domain is registered and correctly set up to match your server, you don't need anything in your /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Was doing some research and it looks like it takes about 24-48 hours for the DNS to propagate. On a whim I typed my domain and it worked. Thanks for your help.